# Tkinter widgets not showing up in Hummingbird Exceed

Tags: python, tkinter, xming, exceed

I created a GUI using Tkinter and tested it in windows.  When I run it in windows, everything appears as it should.  When I run the GUI in Linux using Hummingbird Exceed, all of the buttons (a total of 2) do not show up.  Yet, when I run the same script in Linux using Xming, I do not have any problems.  I am wondering why Tkinter does not work in Exceed.

What is interesting is that I have created other GUIs using Tkinter before and ran them with exceed, and I have never had a problem.  I originally thought that I could have possibly changed some background settings that I am unaware of.  Although, I tried the same script on other people's Linux accounts and I still got the same problem.  I could not find anything online about the display specifications for Tkinter, so if anyone has any ideas on why this is happening, please let me know.  I also checked to see if it was a version problem with Python, Tkinter, Anaconda, etc and it doesn't seem to be that as well. I appreciate your help.

Comment: _"I am wondering why Tkinter does not work in Exceed."_: have you contacted exceed customer support?

Comment: I have not.  Talking to Exceed and the Tkinter folks would definitely be the next step.